# React Table not sorting numbers correctly

Tags: reactjs, react-table

React-table is sorting decimals like this:

[image]

My guess is that, although I'm receiving numbers from server, react-table handles them as text. So, I modified the accessor like this:

```
accessor: d => Number(d.Invoice_Weight).toFixed(2)
```

but I keep getting the sorting wrong.

This is the code for column:

```
 {
                      Header: () => 
                      <DropDownMenu 
                      header={content[lang].Invoice_Weight}
                      openModal = {this.onOpenSelectColumnsModal}
                      />,
                      id: 'Invoice_Weight',
                      sortable: true,
                      accessor: d => Number(d.Invoice_Weight).toFixed(2),
                      //width: 200,
                      getProps: () => {
                        return {
                          style: {
                            textAlign: 'right'
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      show: Invoice_Weight,
                    },
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As suggested in other answers the issue is that `toFixed` returns a string and therefore the sorting will be done using string comparisons. However coercing back to number will not work in this case becase then you will lose trailing `0`s which I'm guessing you still need.

Another solution is to use custom sorting:

```js
accessor: d => Number(d.Invoice_Weight).toFixed(2),
sortMethod: (a, b) => Number(a)-Number(b)
```

You may want to refine `sortMethod` to handle NaNs and Infinities (if you have them) but that's the general idea

You can use this to coerce the string back to a number but only in the context of sorting without affecting the displayed value

Answer (score 4):

My guess is this is caused by the fact that `.toFixed()` returns a string, so it is still sorting them as strings.  So if you want to round the number and keep it as two decimal places you would have to do something like this:

```js
accessor: d => Number(Number(d.Invoice_Weight).toFixed(2))
```

So convert it to a number first, round it to a two decimal place string, and then convert it back to a number again.

Comment: Chris, thank you very much! Your answer did solve the problem but the thing is that I lost the zeros (,00) of decimals so I think I'll use apokryfos' solution. Thank you both!

Comment: No problem, after reading his answer I realized it is definitely the way to go if you did need to maintain the trailing zeros!

Answer (score 1):

Default sorting method of React Table provides sorting by string.so you have to use  sortMethod props provided by React Table.

```
sortMethod: (a, b) => {
   a = Number(a); // Converting into number
   b = Number(b); // Converting into number
   if (a.length === b.length) {
     return a > b ? 1 : -1; // same length condition
   }
   return a.length > b.length ? 1 : -1; // comparing length of string
}
```